# How to implement Paypal subscription in a vue application?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, paypal, vuejs2

I am working on a project which needs to deducts a fixed amount from a user's account to a business account on monthly basis. I am trying to create a Paypal button client side (vue) for accepting subscriptions on monthly basis. The users deduction information on monthly basis shall be stored in a database. The user shall also provided an option to cancel the subscription. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i found out an answer after a little digging in the documentation provided at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate and went through the steps they provided.

Steps

1. Create a product through their API by providing access_token in the headers.
2. After the product has been created, get product-Id from response and then create plan using the product_id in request body.
3. After the plan has been successfully created copy Plan_id and replace the id in smart subscription button.

   ```
   paypal.Buttons({

     createSubscription: function(data, actions) {

           return actions.subscription.create({

                'plan_id': 'P-your_plan_id'

   });
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {

       alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);

            }


   }
   ```